# Artificial Intelligence: Logic and Pro.blem-Solving

Tags: language-agnostic, logic, artificial-intelligence, dijkstra

Firstly: My apologies for putting "Pro.blem" in the title - SO won't let me put "Problem" there.

Anyways, during trig yesterday, I had an idea.  Suppose I want to write a program that utilizes artificial intelligence to solve problems.  I stripped it down to an implementation of Dijkstra's algorithm on a directed graph, using actions as nodes and requirements/results as paths. For example, let's say Fred's in the living room and he's hungry.  Some of Fred's possible actions are:

- Get up:
  Requirements: state = sitting or lying down.
  Results: state = standing.
- Lie down:
  Requirements: state = standing or sitting.
  Results: state = lying down.
- Fall asleep:
  Requirements: state = lying down, location = bedroom.
  Results: state = asleep.
- Walk to kitchen:
  Requirements: state = standing, location is not kitchen.
  Results: location = kitchen.
- Walk to bedroom:
  Requirements: state = standing, location is not bedroom.
  Results: location = bedroom.
- Prepare food:
  Requirements: state = standing, location = kitchen.
  Results: hasfood = true.
- Eat:
  Requirements: hasfood = true.
  Results: hungry = false, hasfood = false.

Actions such as "get up" and "lie down" are easy because there is one requirement and one result.  Actions such as "walk to kitchen" and "walk to bedroom" present more of a problem, because they have more than one requirement.  How can I use requirements/results as a path if paths intertwine with each other?

Ultimately, the question(s):

Could problem solving + pathfinding work in practice (or has it worked already)?  Would it make more sense to use requirements/results as nodes and actions as paths?  If you think this approach is promising, please respond with pseudocode or an explanation for implementation.

Comment: This problem is known in AI as planning. Bookshelfs have been filled out it; see e.g. [*AIMA*](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/), chapters 10-11.

Comment: Yeah exactly as @larsmans said - there is an example called the [Monkey and Banana problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_and_banana_problem) which may be of some interest.